# node.js node-soap - How to set a client instance as a property of a parent object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, constructor, prototype-chain

I am trying to build a module to handle SOAP functionality for the sake of modularity

I use vpulim/node-soap , allthough it's not relevant for my question:

```
var soap = require ( "soap" );

    function SoapController( url ) {

        var self = this; //prevent scope issues

            self.GetClient = function () {

                soap.createClient(
                    url , function ( err , client ) {

                                   self.client = client;
                      console.log( self.client.describe() );
            }
        )
    };
}

module.exports = SoapController;
```

In my Router:

```
SoapOb = require ( "./SoapController.js" );

router.get(
    '/S' , function ( req , res ) {

        var soapC = new SoapOb ( 'http://infovalutar.ro/curs.asmx?wsdl' );

        soapC.GetClient();

        console.log( soapC );
    }
);
```

Results of conlog:
from inside the router:

```
SoapController { GetClient: [Function] }
```

And inside the callback of the createClient method:

```
{ Curs:
   { CursSoap:
      { GetLatestValue: [Object],
        getlatestvalue: [Object],
        getall: [Object],
        getvalue: [Object],
        getvalueadv: [Object],
        GetValue: [Object],
        LastDateInserted: [Object],
        lastdateinserted: [Object] },
     CursSoap12:
      { GetLatestValue: [Object],
        getlatestvalue: [Object],
        getall: [Object],
        getvalue: [Object],
        getvalueadv: [Object],
        GetValue: [Object],
        LastDateInserted: [Object],
        lastdateinserted: [Object] } } }
```

What I need to acomplish is set the client Instance as a property of the SoapController object so i can access it's methods .

I also tried defining the GetClient method through prototype,but it doesn't work , I get undefined in console

```
SoapController.prototype.GetClient = function () {

    var self = this; //prevent scope issues

        soap.createClient(
            self.url , function ( err , client ) {

            self.client = client;
        }
    )
};
```

Please guide me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soap.createClient is an async method. So you have to refactor your getClient method.

```
SoapController.prototype.getClient = function (callback) {
    var self = this;

    soap.createClient(self.url, function (err, client) {
        self.client = client;
        callback();
    })
}
```

now any work you need done must be done inside callback.

```
SoapOb = require ( "./SoapController.js" );

router.get('/S' , function ( req , res ) {
    var soapC = new SoapOb ( 'http://infovalutar.ro/curs.asmx?wsdl' );
    soapC.GetClient(function() {
        console.log(soapC.client);
    });
}
```

);

Comment: Thank you ! I knew it was related to async but I wasn't sure how this works ,you helped me! So , every async func will take another func as argument which will handle the actual logic ,and once done it will return to the initial function ...,right?

Comment: I am a bit disappointed though , the whole point was to have clean code , as few lines as possible inside the router , it was a good exercise anyway.

Comment: you could refactor the router to take a client that is ready to take requests.